# Is there a way to make a hypertext link to a printer

Tags: php, html, printing, protocols

I have a large list of printers on my webapp, I would like to beable to send print jobs to a specific printer from the browser but i cannot find anyway to do this.

Is there a link similar to mailto: for printing.

Comment: how are you retrieving this list of printers?  If its some kind of webservice, chances are you can use the same service to initiate a print job.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to send the print job to the particular printer, the user has to select printer from the list of printer available which we can trigger in JavaScript as follows,

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print();"> Print this page </button>
```